# Open .WetTexture

Tags: hp-and-the-philosophers-stone-pc

I was playing an old unreal game (HP1) and wanted to have a look at the water textures I extracted what I think to be the textures using "Dragon UnPACKer" and got ".WetTexture" files, googling .WetTexture comes up dead (one result)

TLDR: Open or extract ".WetTexture"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WetTexture was a feature of Unreal.

> Water amplitude used as displacement for another texture.

Which is placed under this category:

> UT2003 :: Object >> Material >> RenderedMaterial >> BitmapMaterial >> Texture >> FractalTexture >> WaterTexture >> WetTexture

If you're searching for the images, that's not the file you're looking for.

You can see someone trying to reproduce WetTextures here: https://www.ut99.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=11828